# Issue while retrieving KeyVault Secret

Tags: c#, certificate, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

Trying to retrieve the KeyVault Secret by AD authentication using Certificate.

[Documentation Reffered for Creating KeyVault & AD application using Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application)

> ```
> public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope) {
>     var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
>     var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, AssertionCert);
>     return result.AccessToken; }
> ```

Code fails while

> var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource,AssertionCert)

InnerException contains: "Keyset does not exists"

And some times "Invalid provider type specified." error occurs
Not sure where is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue after running my application as Administrator.

Comment: Salutations/Closings are not required (Your user card displays this information already). They can be perceived as noise for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `AssertionCert` is valid, it's likely a permission issue to access the private key (which is needed for authentication here).

Try this:

- Create a Microsoft Management Console (MMC) with the Certificates
  snap-in that targets the Local Machine certificate store
- Expand the MMC and select Manage Private Keys.
- On the Security tab, add the account you're running with, with Read
  access.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I have already done the settings that you have specified.Instead of only Read access, I have provided full access at the root level for IIS_IUSRS. Now error encountered is "Invalid provider type specified"

Comment: does this post help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2009/12/22/invalid-provider-type-specified-error-when-accessing-x509certificate2-privatekey-on-cng-certificates/

Comment: and this to convert: http://blog.davidchristiansen.com/2016/05/521/#convert

Comment: blog.davidchristiansen.com/2016/05/521.....referred this link but my certificate location is not in the solution...var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestApp.MyCert.pfx")...this code always returns null in my case...even if specify the full path of my certificate..

Comment: Don't use his demo code, use the steps outlined in chapter "Converting your certificate key from CNG to RSA" to convert your certificate (using OpenSSL for Windows).

Comment: I have tried the code for determining whether my certificate has privatekey permissions or not...It is available. But when I try to fetch the CNG key its errors out...HasCNGKey() method has support with X509Certificate2 namespace..not sure whether to retrieve the CNGKey or not?

Comment: I suggest that you check the application's manifest(**keyCredentials** enlement) ensure that the certificate was config well. You can confirm the key via **customKeyIdentifier**. To retrieve the these value, you can use the command `$cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2;$cer.Import("C:\yourCert.cer");$bin = $cer.GetRawCertData();$base64Value = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin);$bin = $cer.GetCertHash();$base64Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin)`. The value of  base64Thumbprint should be the **customKeyIdentifier**.

Answer (score 0):

The KeySet does not exist usually happens when the user you are trying to read the certificate as does not have access to the private keys of the cert. Can you double check your ACLing on the certs?

Comment: Hi Dilip, I got this issue resolved by removing the condition of getting the Certificate from CurrentUser/Local Machine Store. Secondly, I also tried to import the Certificate on Current User context of that Server.